# Is there any way to set the "SameSite" property on a session cookie?

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, cookies

I am having an issue with Chrome and the "samesite" property on my cookies (I am logging in via PHP on a cloud server, then using resources on my cloud server in another domain)

On the cookies I am creating myself, I can do:

```
setcookie("foo", "bar", [
   "expires" => time() + 60 * 60 * 24,
   "path" => "/",
   "domain" => "", 
   "secure" => true,
   "httponly" => false,
   "samesite" => 'None'
  ]);
```

And this works.

My question is, is there any way to add "samesite" => 'None' on my "PHPSESSID" session cookie as well, so I can use the session from a cross domain page?

This is a chrome specific issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it by changing `session.cookie_samesite` inside `php.ini`.

Details [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-samesite)

Comment: Or via session_set_cookie_params function in php, but this question/answers are duplicate.